# Special meaning of 手が挙がる

Tags: expressions

In an email about someone I introduced for a position at a company, one particular sentence was as follows:

○○様、残念ながら誰からも手が挙がらず、お見送りとさせてください。

While I am familiar with the fact that 手が上がる has multiple meanings, I do not see how any of them fits in this context. Can someone enlighten me?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to disappoint you, but

> 「誰からも手が挙がらず」

means "***no one agreed to hire [this individual]***"

Whether or not those involved were asked to physically raise their hands if they agreed to hire him/her is beside the point because 「手を挙げる」 already has an idiomatic meaning of "**to say yes**".